# Cassandra high disk space utilization

Tags: cassandra

We have a 12 node cassandra cluster in Production. In the recent past, almost all the nodes are using higher than 85% disc space. We tried to add default_time_to_live, gc_grace_seconds for few tables. But there seems to be no effect on the count of records or the disc space.
There are suggestions to perform nodetool compact and cleanup. But this also mentions that it is not suggested to be run on production environment.

Some specific questions,

1. Tried setting the TTL as 100 days and gc as 3hours. Expectation was records older than 90 days should get deleted after 3 hours. But it was still intact. Is there anything else to be taken care to delete records older than 100 days using TTL settings? Disc space is also expected to be freed up. Again what else should be done to free up disc space after deleting records.

```
ALTER TABLE my_keyspace.my_item WITH default_time_to_live=8640000
ALTER TABLE my_keyspace.my_item WITH gc_grace_seconds=10800
```

2. Is it ok to run nodetool compact followed by nodetool cleanup on a prod environment with all instances over 85% disc space utilized?

Please share other suggestions as well to free up disc space utilized by Cassandra.

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.1.x.x  997.26 GiB  256          24.7%             erff8abf-16a1-4a72-b63e-5c4rg2c8d003  rack1
UN  10.2.x.x   1.22 TiB   256          26.1%             a8auuj76-f635-450f-a2fd-7sdfg0ss713e  rack1
UN  10.3.x.x   1.21 TiB   256          25.4%             8ebas25c-4c0b-4be9-81e3-013fasdas255  rack1
UN  10.4.x.x   1.27 TiB   256          25.1%             wwwdba15-16f3-41a8-b3d1-2d2b6e35715d  rack1
UN  10.5.x.x  975.67 GiB  256          24.7%             72ed4df7-fb65-4332-b8ac-e7461699f633  rack1
UN  10.6.x.x  1.01 TiB   256          24.8%             39803f58-127f-453b-b102-ed7bdfb8afb2  rack1
UN  10.7.x.x  1.18 TiB   256          25.9%             b6e692a6-249f-433d-8b54-1d20d4bc4962  rack1
UN  10.8.x.x  1.12 TiB   256          24.5%             8ed8c306-9ac9-4130-bff1-97f7d5d9a02f  rack1
UN  10.9.x.x  973.26 GiB  256          24.4%             f7489923-3cc3-43ec-83ca-42bbdeb0cbb7  rack1
UN  10.10.x.x  1.13 TiB   256          26.0%             ea694224-ds0b-42f5-9acf-ff4ddfb450e0  rack1
UN  10.11.x.x   1.22 TiB   256          24.0%            ddde4bce-553e-4246-9920-47sdfdf324ed  rack1
UN  10.12.x.x  1.28 TiB   256          24.4%             0222d40f-edb8-4710-9bae-39dsfd87e18db  rack1
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Setting a default TTL on a table will only apply to **newly inserted data**. If you recall, SSTables are immutable in Cassandra -- they don't get updated/modified once they've been written to disk. This means that any existing data in the SSTables will *not* have the new TTL applied to them so it won't free up any disk space.
2. Forcing a major compaction will *not* make a difference because of (1) -- the existing data in the SSTables will not expire. The default TTL will only apply to new mutations/writes (inserts/updates). For the same reason, running `nodetool cleanup` won't make a difference either since there's nothing to cleanup. In any case, major compactions are a bad idea in C* as I've explained in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/6396/.

So how do you deal with low disk space on existing nodes? You need to increase the capacity of your cluster by adding more nodes. As you add nodes one by one, you can run `nodetool cleanup` on the existing nodes to immediately free up space.

I've done some rough calculations based on the average node density of 1153GB across all 12 nodes. If you add 1 node, it will free up ~89GB per node on average. If you add 2 nodes, it should free up ~165GB per node on average. 3 nodes is about a 231GB drop and 4 nodes about 288GB. Cheers!

Comment: I agree that adding a node is probably the best approach.  At 85% full, it's likely that compactions don't have enough room to run to completion.

Comment: Thank you. Please suggest if just adding extra node helps or increasing the disc space of existing instance/s would work as well. We already have 12 nodes and we do not want to end up having more nodes to manage !

Comment: And I am also looking at a long term solution for having cassandra instance/s space under control. I can understand that the suggestions to add extra nodes comes in as the state of the cluster is beyond control. But how do I ensure that I don't end up in the same situation!

Comment: I also want to ensure that records older than 100 days are cleaned up automatically. If setting the TTL today will start taking effect only after 100 days, how can I clear up the records older than that. Will deleting the records manually and then enabling a lesser gc_grace_seconds(say minimum 3 hours), ensure that the records and the tombstones are deleted?

Comment: Posted on https://community.datastax.com/questions/12155/cassandra-high-disc-space-utilization.html as well

Comment: Erick - I added a new node and marked the first 3 as CASSANDRA_SEEDS(as owns was ~25%). Bootstrapping is still in progress for the new node and the load seems to be higher than the other nodes. The host also went out of disc space and even after updating twice the disc space of the other clusters, it is still unable to complete bootstrap and went out of disc space again. Please confirm if I am proceeding in the right direction or if there is anything wrong in the cassandra seeds selection.

Comment: The node could get successfully added by mentioning the cassandra seeds as 1

Comment: I'm not sure what "by mentioning the cassandra seeds as 1" means. Can you please elaborate? Cheers!

Comment: The Cassandra seed was set to just one node.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the data does not mean it will go away immediately physically. It is the baseline `(deletion time + gc_grace_seconds)` after which data may get removed via process of compaction. Till compaction does not happen on intended tables you will have data on your disc. Coming back to your question of reducing disc space. You can try any one of the option which suits your case.

1. `Run nodetool compact`. Use this option judiciously. Since compaction itself requires space, so identify the keyspace tables which can be compacted without killing the node due to disc space shortage. Also use `-s` option if you have STCS on your table.
2. Set `unchecked_tombstone_compaction` to true. This solves a lot of problem. If you have lot of tombstones then this will trigger single table compaction.
3. Use user defined compaction to run compaction on selected sstables.
4. If your application permits, you can truncate the table if it is having lot of useless data and repopulate the table with the required data.

You can refer this [blog](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) by Alain Rodriguez to understand tombstones and how to cleanup.

Note: Before applying any procedure test on your test environment first.

Comment: I did a test on pre prod environment and I could find that nodetool compact indeed clears up disc space for us. I also noticed that the disc space went upto 87%(during compaction) from 73% and then reduced to 60%(after compaction is done). I will try -s option in Prod.

Comment: Test your procedure before running on prod thoroughly. Theory and practical are two different beasts.

Comment: @Radhika Running compaction manually should be an option of last resort.  Once you do that, you'll need to run it manually in perpetuity, as the resulting SSTable file sizes will greatly reduce the chances of repair ever running organically in the future.

Comment: @Radhika see Erick's answer.  I think adding another node is your best option here.

Comment: Agree with @Aaron there, running compaction should be one of the last resort. If you have the option to add another node then that is the best option.

Comment: Thank you. Please suggest if just adding extra node helps or increasing the disc space of existing instance/s would work as well. We already have 12 nodes and we do not want to end up having more nodes to manage !

Comment: And I am also looking at a long term solution for having cassandra instance/s space under control. I can understand that the suggestions to add extra nodes comes in as the state of the cluster is beyond control. But how do I ensure that I don't end up in the same situation!

Comment: I also want to ensure that records older than 100 days are cleaned up diligently. If setting the TTL today will start taking effect only after 100 days, how can I clear up the records older than that.  Will deleting the records manually and then enabling a lesser gc_grace_seconds(say minimum 3 hours), ensure that the records and the tombstones are deleted?

Comment: As @Erick mentioned in his answer, compaction will not be of any help in your case as you were not setting ttl earlier, so at present best option is to add nodes. For future you can add ttl to your data that will allow data to move out slowly. Also for old data, you can consider repopulating required data and truncating the  old data.